# Send a message to a text channel when a person joins a specific voice channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to make my bot that notifies my server staff in a specific text channel when someone enters the voice support waiting room.

Unfortunately, I only found some examples for Discord version 12, and it's not working for me in version 13. I don't know what to change in that code.

There is no error message or anything, it just doesn't send a message when someone is joining the voice channel.

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
  const newUserChannel = newState.channelID;
  const textChannel = client.channels.cache.get('931223643362703521');

  if (newUserChannel === '931156705303317013') {
    textChannel.send('Somebody joined');
  }
  console.error();
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with it? Is there any error?

Comment: Theres no error message or anything it just doesn't send a message when someone is joining the voice Channel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you add the `GUILD_VOICE_STATES` intent.

It's probably better to [`fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch) the channel, instead of relying on the cache. If the channel is already cached, `fetch` will use that and won't make a request to the discord API, but if it's not cached, `channels.cache.get` won't find it.

I've made a couple of changes and added some comments in the code below:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES,
  ],
});

client.on('voiceStateUpdate', async (oldState, newState) => {
  const VOICE_SUPPORT_ID = '931156705303317013';
  const LOG_CHANNEL_ID = '931223643362703521';
  // if there is no newState channel, the user has just left a channel
  const USER_LEFT = !newState.channel;
  // if there is no oldState channel, the user has just joined a channel
  const USER_JOINED = !oldState.channel;
  // if there are oldState and newState channels, but the IDs are different,
  // user has just switched voice channels
  const USER_SWITCHED = newState.channel?.id !== oldState.channel?.id;

  // if a user has just left a channel, stop executing the code 
  if (USER_LEFT)
    return;

  if (
    // if a user has just joined or switched to a voice channel
    (USER_JOINED || USER_SWITCHED) &&
    // and the new voice channel is the same as the support channel
    newState.channel.id === VOICE_SUPPORT_ID
  ) {
    try {
      let logChannel = await client.channels.fetch(LOG_CHANNEL_ID);

      logChannel.send(
        `${newState.member.displayName} joined the support channel`,
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('❌ Error finding the log channel, check the error below');
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }
  }
});
```

In discord.js v14, you'll need to add the following intents:

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates,
  ],
});
```

Comment: All guild channels are cached as far as I know, so no need to fetch

Comment: @MrMythical I'm not sure. I was pretty sure (until reading your comment) that I've had cases where channels were not cached. But now that you've mentioned it, I'm wondering if it was a guild? I'm changing the wording of my answer though :)

Comment: All guilds are also cached by default though...

Comment: I know, they should be cached, but [sometimes they are not](https://www.reddit.com/r/Discordjs/comments/r2ephd/comment/hm5mufy/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).