# How do I detect when a person joins a vc discord.js v13?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Hey whoever is reading this! I'm trying to make it so when someone joins a voice channel a variable goes up and when they leave it goes down, but when I try using the voiceStateUpdate event it doesn't do anything and then I put a console.log() into that event and it didn't log so I don't know if its the same in v13, and if there is something in the discord.js guid please respond with the link!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [User connected to voice channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62637725/user-connected-to-voice-channel)

Comment: nope it doesn't work! it should but it doesnt!

Comment: can you please provide code, it's very difficult to determine your issue without a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or errors being raised?

Comment: i dont think the event is being run for some reason!

Comment: you need the `GUILD_VOICE_STATES` intent. `const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES] });` - i'll formalise this in an answer

Comment: thank you can you let me put this in an answer!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send a message to a text channel when a person joins a specific voice channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70700068/send-a-message-to-a-text-channel-when-a-person-joins-a-specific-voice-channel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to use `voiceStateUpdate` event, your client must declare the `GUILD_VOICE_STATE` intent in order to receive data about the voice state of the guild.

When initialising your client:

`client = new Client({ intents: [..., Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES] });`